# Is it possible to close the auto-complete SuggestWidget programmatically?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm in the process of migrating from Codemirror to Monaco editor for a project where we use a prefix key to type in special characters. For example, given a prefix of `.`, if the user types `.` followed by `o` the editor replaces the sequence with `Ω`.

It is possible to use the addCommand and provide it a chord, like this:

```
editor.addCommand(
  monaco.KeyMod.chord(monaco.KeyCode.US_DOT , monaco.KeyCode.KEY_O),
  x=>{ // write out special char here 
    editor.executeEdits("", [
      { range: editor.getSelection(), text: "Ω" }
    ]);
  }
)
```

But I want to use the auto-complete feature to help the user by listing the special chars once they type the prefix key. A CompletionItemProvider allows me to do that by providing the prefix key in the triggerCharacters property:

```
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('mylang', {
  triggerCharacters:['.'],
  provideCompletionItems: (model,position,token) => { 
    let l=position.lineNumber,c=position.column;
    let s=model.getLineContent(l),ch=s[c-2];
    console.log('completion triggered on: '+ch)
    if (ch==='.'){
      return CompletionItem[]; // return list of valid special chars
    }
  }
})
```

Now I get the list of suggestions when the user types the prefix key, but even if he follows that with an `o`, it doesn't trigger until he commits by hitting enter or selecting the item with the mouse. I can attach a listener to spot a valid sequence and do the replacement that way:

```
editor.model.onDidChangeContent(e=>{
  if (valid sequence) 
    editor.executeEdits('',[{range,text:'Ω'}])

})
```

This works, but I'm left with the SuggestionWizard open.

The immediate question is if there is any way I can control programmatically when to hide the widget?

Secondary, is there a better way to achieve the above?

#### Update:

Found a hack to get it closed using private methods. Not happy to use this approach for obvious reasons, but also because it seems to require a delayed action that I haven't managed to pinpoint the reason for yet.

```
let sw=editor._view.contentWidgets._widgets["editor.widget.suggestWidget"]
setTimeout(x=>sw&&sw._actual&&sw._actual.hideWidget(),50)
```

Answer (score 6):

That no longer works or did not work for me, however this did:

```
editorinstance.trigger('editor','hideSuggestWidget', []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the command to trigger:

`editorinstance.trigger('editor', 'cancelSuggestWidget')`

I wonder if there is an easy way to list all available commands...